# Django Import-Export proxy model

Tags: python, django, excel, django-admin

i would like to export to a XLS file my data in the Admin, i tried Import-Export (with admin integration) and works great, the problem here is, i'm already using a model, so i need to export a proxy model to XLS, can you help me please?, with this code the model appears, and the import, export menu appears too, but when i try to export or import i got this error:

```
**StopIteration
No exception message supplied**
```

**Admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *
from django.utils.html import format_html_join
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ExportarDatosPromo(Promo):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class PromoCountResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Promo

class PromoCountAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title_description1', 'description1', 'offer', 'coupon_code', 'count')
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'title_description1', 'description1', 'offer', 'coupon_code', 'count')

admin.site.register(ExportarDatosPromo, PromoCountAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, because nobody answer anything, i fix my error. The problem is, if you have a Taggit (Django-Taggit) field in your model, Django Import-Export App will not work, so you have to delete the field (and there is no other app for tagging actually working), and import-export will work just fine.

If you want to continue to use django taggit as an app, just put your field in a model with a foreign key to your original model.